# Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

Hello, How do i create the permanent notification like the first one for Battery Indicator?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Assign `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` flag to your `Notification`.

Sample code:

```
yourNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
// Notify...
```

If you aren't familiar with the `Notification` API, read [Creating Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on Android developers website.

Comment: Also you should start ongoing notifications with `Service.startForeground` NOT using `NotificationManager.notify()`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `|=`, not `=`?

Comment: And how would I dismiss the notification once my ongoing task is over ?

Answer (score 91):

In case you are using `NotificationCompat.Builder` , you can use :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
mBuilder.setOngoing(true); //this will make ongoing notification
```

Comment: upvote because Now for creating notifications we should use Builder.

Comment: it need to targetSDK is 23

Comment: @Mahmoud how do I dismiss it later?

Comment: NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.cancel(mNotificationID);

Answer (score 50):

It is actually recommended to bitwise-or notification flags, rather than set the flags directly. This allows you to set multiple flags at once.

For example:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

will set both flags at once, whereas:

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

will only set the FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS flag.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static final int FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
```

Since: API Level 1
Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if this notification is in reference to something that is ongoing, like a phone call.

```
public static final int FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
```

Since: API Level 5 
Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if this notification represents a currently running service.