# Android notification like Skype Application

Tags: android, notifications

I'm writing an application for my Android phone. The application has a background service. I want to display that service in the notification area like Skype application does.
If I use NotificationManager and Notification (the way android samples do), the result is different.

[See this image](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2092/device20120113215429.png)

My notification is the one called "Service".
The Skype service has an icon just above the notification area. Skype has also "normal notifications". These "normal notifications" appear below my notification.

I want my service to be above the notification area like Skype application is. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a note for good UX, when using the Ongoing Event notifications always provide an option in the app to disable such notifications to avoid annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

Also look at

[Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693997/android-how-to-create-an-ongoing-notification)

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html