# Show Applicaiton in Ongoind mode in Statusbar android

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Hello friends i want to show my application as like below screen in our mobile notification detail

[image]

Any idea how can i achieve this?

**My Custom Dialog**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT flag to your Notification.

Sample code:

```
yourNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
// Notify...
```

If you aren't familiar with the Notification API, read Creating Status Bar Notifications on Android developers website.

Source:
[Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693997/android-how-to-create-an-ongoing-notification)

Comment: Thnkas for posting it is working ,but can i get click event in "+" sign because i want to open my custom dialog which i show  in my question