# How to make notification stay on top?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a notification which I always want to stay on top.

**I have already given it a priority of 2**

Mostly it stays on top but, suppose there is a open WiFi network, then my notification goes down and the notification of open WiFi network comes on the top position.

But when I looked at the notification of vlc(for Android) paying a song, the notification of vlc stay on top and the notification of open WiFi network goes down.

I notification is ongoing and with priority 2.

What should I do. I am a beginner so please bear with me.

And thanks in advance.

Comment: VLC displays an ongoing notification.

Comment: did u set  .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); ?

Comment: Well, yes but i have given it max. numerical value. i.e. 2 as priority.and yeah, my mortifications are also ongoing.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("ON Top")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

Priority Levels --> `PRIORITY_MAX` / `PRIORITY_HIGH` /`PRIORITY_DEFAULT` /`PRIORITY_LOW` /`PRIORITY_MIN`

read
https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#priority

and as  StenSoft said 
[Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693997/android-how-to-create-an-ongoing-notification)

Comment: Notification.PRIORITY_MAX always leads to highlight like when you move background to foreground it popup on the app but we can't say it is on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to this code:

```
Intent push = new Intent();
    push.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    push.setClass(this, NotificationDemo.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification updateNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_face_black_24dp)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("Priority Max Notification Title")
            .setContentText("Priority Max Notification Message")
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pi,true)
            .build();



    nm.notify("priorityMaxTest",2,updateNotification);
```

Comment: Well, according to me max priority is 2 and i have already given it.