# Android: How to create a permanent notification using NotificationChannel

Tags: android, notification-channel

Do you know which method I am supposed to use to create a permanent Notification using NotificationChannel in Android Pie? More precisely, a notification that the user cant remove.

Comment: What do you mean "permanent Notification" ? what did you tried?

Comment: A notification that the user cant remove (I edited the question)

Comment: You make notification in service?

Comment: start a foreground service

Comment: Yes it has been created in a service.

Comment: imho there is no option like you want https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html you can make it via NotificationCompat.Builder or via notification.flags from Notification class

Comment: Also when you call notification via `startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification);` user cant remove it if you don't call `stopForeground(true);` and not changed `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` of notification.

Comment: Ha ok! THank you for your answers

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your question than your permanent notification is called ongoing notification.

You can use

```
setOngoing(true)
```

for your

```
NotificationCompat.Builder
```

However this question seems to be duplicated: please see more here:

[Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693997/android-how-to-create-an-ongoing-notification)

Comment: No because I am talking about NotificationCHannel which is not the case in the question you show

Comment: Notification Channels are created before you send notifications via that channel, for that sending you probably still would use NotificationCompat where you can use setOngoing.
Or you mean you would like all notifications of a channel to be ongoing?
I am not sure if that is possible with Android SDK
As far as I know you have to set it individually for each notifications.

Comment: Ha ok! Thank you for your reply!